# Do not consider white spaces and quotes using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I have below string:

```
Values: Fail.123/urs/temp/lib.000
```

I need to create a regular expression which will not consider the spaces and "". And It should not be case sensitive also.
If I will pass above string `(Values: Fail.123/urs/temp/lib.000)`. it will show the below strings also:

```
value:Fail.123/urs/temp/lib.000 
Value:fail.123  /urs/temp/Lib.000
value:"fail.123 /urs/temp/Lib.000
```

Comment: How about clearing the string of spaces and quotes and then matching with ignorecase?

Comment: Just remove the extra space with re.sub(r"^\s+", "") but it is not a proper way..It will not work for other strings

Comment: Do you want to ignore `{}` (curly brackets) or `"` (quotes)?

Comment: I want to ignore "(quotes)

Comment: can you give us an example string and explain what exactly do you want your regex to match and what not. That is, give us the input you have and the output that you would like to have.

Comment: Please show us an example with both white space and quotes, and what should be the output

Comment: actually i am dealing with the database when i am passing this string i will return only one row but others row are also similar to this one for that i want the regular expression to retrieve all the similar row like above results.

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression will ignore white space and `"` (quotes):

```
[^\s"]*
```

PS: I tested this using .NET regular expressions but it should work for python

Comment: I am using this regular expression b = re.sub(r'[(\s")*]','[\s]*',a) but still not getting the answers

Comment: You're welcome Surya, if it's working then you can upvote my answer and/or mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you the idea:

```
In [76]: cmpkey = lambda s:re.sub(r'[\s"]', '', s).lower()

In [77]: cmpkey('Values: Fail.123/urs/temp/lib.000') == key('values:"fail.123 /urs/temp/Lib.000')
Out[77]: True
```

P.S. I just noticed that in your example, "value" is used interchangeably with "values". Why is that?

Comment: its working for you but retrieving the data from DB its not showing any rows